# Does not compile ffmpeg

Tags: c, gcc, ffmpeg

Translated.

I have a problem. When I try to compile a file in which h files ffmpeg are connected using gcc, I get an error that in the code ffmpeg is incorrectly written include, and it means that the file is in the current directory, although it should be in the next directory. How to fix it?

Includes in my C file:

```
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libswscale/swscale.h"
```

Error:

```
D:\gcc\bin>gcc -o a a.c -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lz -
lavutil -lm
In file included from a.c:3:0: libavcodec/avcodec.h:31:33: 
fatal error: libavutil/samplefmt.h: No such file or directory 
#include "libavutil/samplefmt.h"
^
compilation terminated.
```

My answer:

I was able to solve the problem only by fixing the source code. First I added the libavutil/avconfig.h file with the contents:

```
  #ifndef AVUTIL_AVCONFIG_H
  #define AVUTIL_AVCONFIG_H
  #define AV_HAVE_BIGENDIAN 0
  #define AV_HAVE_FAST_UNALIGNED 0
  #endif
```

Then if I saw an error where the directory and the file (libavutil/avutil) participate, I added "../" there, since this is the case where the directory is located next to the one where the file that caused the error is (../libavutil/avutil.h). In another case, if this file should be inside (only if the directory name matches the current one (libavutil/avutil.h)), you can either just leave the file name (avutil.h), or also add "../", the difference will not be. Such operations need to be repeated about 20 times until errors in all header files disappear. After that, you can safely compile ffmpeg without special knowledge and patches. Code for avconfig.h found on the Chinese site.

Comment: You can also checkout https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ffmpeg-php/fjzVQDL-QF4

Comment: I do not understand anything there. What is the problem? And I have Windows MinGW.

Comment: Help! How compile this with gcc?

Answer (score 0):

your 'compile' statement is missing the location of the header file.  Suggest:

the compile/link statement should be similar to:

```
gcc -o a a.c -I./libavutil   -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lz -lavutil -lm
```

Caveat: I wrote the `-I` parameter as if the current/working directory contains `libavutil` as a sub directory.  If this is not correct, then that parameter will need to be tweaked.

Comment: This not help for me. I attempt -I./libavutil , -I./libavcodec , -I./libavformat. Why I see error in file avcodec.h? Edit this file and fix wrong directory? Or What???

Comment: you could start with `-I./libavutil , -I./libavcodec , -I./libavformat` is not correct, there are no commas between the parameters

Comment: gcc -o a a.c -I./libavutil -I./libavcodec -I./libavformat -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lz   did not help. How else to fix the dependencies?

Comment: regarding: `-lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec`  (assuming that those are the sub directories and short form of the library names) ` -L./avutil -lavutil -L./avformat -lavformat -L./avcodec -lavcodec`